# fscanf() not writing value scaned from file

Tags: c, stdio

I wrote some functions.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long long studentID;
    DATE date;
    char address[256];
    unsigned short isInfected;
}NAT;

int ReadAllNAT(NAT** AllNATPtr) {
    FILE* NATSet = NULL;
    NATSet = fopen("NATData", "r");
    int dataNum = 0;
    NAT* AllNAT = NULL;
    if (NATSet != NULL) {
        fscanf(NATSet, "%d\tDataNum", &dataNum);
        AllNAT = (NAT*)malloc(dataNum * sizeof(NAT));
        for (int i = 0; i < dataNum; i++) {
            fscanf(NATSet, "%lld", &AllNAT[i].studentID);
            fscanf(NATSet, "%d-%d-%d", &AllNAT[i].date.year, &AllNAT[i].date.month, &AllNAT[i].date.day);
            fscanf(NATSet, "%d", &AllNAT[i].isInfected);
            fscanf(NATSet, "%s", AllNAT[i].address);
            fscanf(NATSet, "END");
        }
        fclose(NATSet);
        *AllNATPtr = AllNAT;
    }
    return dataNum;
}

int WriteNAT(const NAT* newNAT, const NAT* AllNAT, int dataNum) {
    FILE* NATSet = NULL;
    NATSet = fopen("NATData", "w");
    int isSucceed = 0;
    if (NATSet != NULL) {
        fprintf(NATSet, "%d\tDataNum\n", (dataNum + 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < dataNum; i++) {
            fprintf(NATSet, "ID\t%lld\tDate-y\t%d\tDate-m\t%d\tDate-d\t%d\tAddress\t%s\tI\t%d\tEND\n", AllNAT[i].studentID, AllNAT[i].date.year, AllNAT[i].date.month, AllNAT[i].date.day, AllNAT[i].address, AllNAT[i].isInfected);
        }
        fprintf(NATSet, "ID\t%lld\tDate-y\t%d\tDate-m\t%d\tDate-d\t%d\tAddress\t%s\tI\t%d\tEND\n", newNAT->studentID, newNAT->date.year, newNAT->date.month, newNAT->date.day, newNAT->address, newNAT->isInfected);
        fclose(NATSet);
        isSucceed = 1;
    }
    return isSucceed;
}
```

I use them to change a file. Those functions can add new line to this file.

```
2   DataNum
ID  11  Date-y  1   Date-m  1   Date-d  1   Address 1   I   0   END
ID  12  Date-y  1   Date-m  1   Date-d  1   Address 1   I   0   END
```

The number "2" stands for the number of lines.

But something went wrong. I use debug mode to find the value of the struct. I saw fscan() didn't write the value which scaned from file and return 0. I changed MSVC to MinGW-gcc, but it still doesn't work. How to make fscanf() works properly? Do I need to redesign a new formant of it? Please lend me a hand. I will be very grateful.

Comment: Are ID Date-y strings present in the file? If they are, you will have to skip them explicitely. Anyway using a `scanf` family function without testing its return value is an guarantee that problems will occur at a time... Furthermore, if the input is line oriented, using `fscanf` means that you blindly trust the file to be abolutely syntactically correct.

Comment: You don't have `-` between the parts of the date, like the format string expects.

Comment: Generally, the answer to "How to make "fscanf()" work properly?" is that it works as designed already.  On the other hand, the answer to the alternative question "How do I make `fscanf()` read my data as I intend?" is often "with great difficulty, if at all".  The latter is especially true if you cannot trust your data to be error-free, which usually you can't in the real world.

Comment: CloudRing, Review `fscanf(NATSet, "%d-%d-%d", &AllNAT[i].date.year, &AllNAT[i].date.month, &AllNAT[i].date.day);` and explain why code used `%d-%d-%d` to match  "Date-y  1   Date-m  1   Date-d  1".

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's my falut. I had change the code in function ReadAllNAT(), but at that time I didn't build the new version.

Comment: `fscanf(NATSet, "ID\t%lld\tDate-y\t%d\tDate-m\t%d\tDate-d\t%d\tAddress\t%s\tI\t%d\tEND\n", &AllNAT[i].studentID, &AllNAT[i].date.year, &AllNAT[i].date.month, &AllNAT[i].date.day, AllNAT[i].address, &AllNAT[i].isInfected);`
This is the code which match the format. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: @CloudRing Why use `"%d"` in `"...%d\tEND..."`?  Is the matching argument an `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make "fscanf()" works properly?

(OP used the wrong format, wrong specifiers, %s lacked width & swapped 2 structure members)

Do not use `fscanf()` to read as it makes error detection and recovery difficult.

Instead use `fgets()` for *all* file input to read a *line* into a *string* ...

```
char buf[sizeof(NAT) * 2]; // be generous
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, NATSet)) {
```

... and now parse.   To parse the string, one nice way uses `sscanf()` with `" %n"` to detect the complete parsing of one line.

```
  // ID  11  Date-y  1   Date-m  1   Date-d  1   Address 1   I   0   END
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, "ID %llu Date-y %d Date-m %d Date-d %d Address %255s I %hu END %n",
     &AllNAT[i].studentID, &AllNAT[i].date.year, &AllNAT[i].date.month,
     &AllNAT[i].date.day, AllNAT[i].address, &AllNAT[i].isInfected, &n);
  if (n == 0 || buf[n]) {
    printf("Invalid input <%s>\n", buf);
  }
```

Note: `"%255s"` will not well parse an address with spaces in it.  To handle that, post sample input.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your method is very useful. It helps me a lot. I'm very appreciated.